# zsh compose command using variable

Tags: zsh

What's the equivalent in `zsh` of the following in `bash`?

```bash
export del='--timeout=0 --wait=0 --force'
kubectl delete pod testpod $del
```

executed in `bash` it return the correct command without problem while the same in `zsh` is returning:

```
Error: invalid argument "0 --wait=0 --force" for "--timeout" flag: time: unknown unit " --wait=" in duration "0 --wait=0 --force"
```

Because this will be using to write repeating command it should do simple to be reproduced.

Current solutions but "too long" to be the answer:

```bash
echo $del | xargs kubectl delete pod testpod
```

```bash
eval kubectl delete pod testpod $del
```

```bash
kubectl delete pod testpod ${=del}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The faster solution I have found is to enable the `zsh` flag for work split variable by default as bash is normally doing

```bash
setopt SH_WORD_SPLIT
kubectl delete pod testpod $del
```

this way I can use the name form of bash
Thanks @user1934428 for give me the right hint

Comment: I personally dislike this, because you turn it on for the rest of the script (until it is turned off again), and it is difficult to maintain code where you first have to check what features are in effect at each line. Basically the default is the one you usually want to have; that's why it is the default. With your setting, you would always have to quote variables when you  do not want word splitting to occur after parameter expansion. The bash way is an inheritance from old Unix Shell times and kept just for compatibility.

Comment: That's true but normally script are always shebanged to be executed with bash script so I don't think this will cause any problems

Answer (score 2):

In zsh you would write

```
kubectl delete pod testpod ${(z)del}
```

The `(z)` tells zsh to do word splitting on the argument.

Comment: This works and it gives me the right hint to find the perfect solution that I will post.

Answer (score 0):

Try with `xargs`:

```
echo $del | xargs kubectl delete pod testpod
```

Comment: While this works it's a "long solution"
Because this will be a repeating command it should be shorter has possible.
I've updated the question accordingly

Thanks!